# How to use container-managed security with SPNEGO and Kerberos?

Tags: jakarta-ee, kerberos, spnego

I'm having a problem with my web app (JSF+JPA). I deploy it on Glassfish (3.1.1). For authentication I must use AD with Kerberos (LDAP auth is not allowed in my organization). I created an SPNEGO filter for this. Then I use local database to search for authenticated user and read her/his profile, roles, etc. All of security checks I do mostly by validating user's session bean in a "rendered" attribute.

My question is: is it possible (in a described environment) to somehow set current user's (principal?) roles *automagically* right after the authorization from data tables, so I could use container-managed security?

I can provide more code/configuration details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a Active Directory-driven realm which will retrieves all AD groups for the presented `UserPrincipalName` from Kerberos.

Comment: 1. Authentication must by done by Kerberos, not LDAP - is this approach compliant? 2. User roles/groups are stored in local DB an willnot/cannot be created in AD - is it possible to use non-AD data store for authorization?

Comment: Yes, of course you can do that. Just make sure that the realm supports that. Otherwise you'd need to write your own.